# Can I customize Content Type for InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I want users to be able to input just an interger between 0 to 9, but there is no default ContentType that i can use (The closest one is IntegerNumber). If it is possible, how can I do it. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validation by setting [`OnValidateInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.OnValidateInput.html) callback and filter user input there.